# Transpose Dataframe without losing data

Tags: r

I am trying to switch rows and columns when I use the code below, it does that but it then removes some of the rows that I have tried to just switch into columns.

```
row.names(SA) <- SA[,1]
SA2 <- data.table::transpose(SA)
rownames(SA2) <- colnames(SA)
colnames(SA2) <- rownames(SA)
SA <- SA2
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example of `SA` that illustrates the problem?

Comment: If you want to switch rownames and colnames, perhaps `SA_transposed <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(SA[-1])), SA[[1]])`? It's hard to know without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: use `keep.names` and `make.names` parameters of the `transpose` function